# Inverse Normal Distribution, why is this z value negative?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a Normal Distribution with unknown mean:

D ~ N(u - 30, 28.09)

and I know P(D < 4) = 0.1

If I use the Inverse Normal Distribution with u = 0, s.d. = 1 and area = 0.1 I get z = 1.2816

But in the mark scheme they say z = -1.2816 (i.e negative my value).

I know it's symmetrical after standardizing (so doesn't really matter) but I would like to understand how to know this z value was negative?

Mark scheme:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to play close attention to what region you're trying to find, and what region your given "inverse normal distribution" is telling you.

You can also use some *rules of thumb* as sanity checks, to make sure you've got the right value. The most relevant one for your question is the fact that the standard normal distribution is symmetric about 0, so $P(Z < 0) = P(Z > 0) = 0.5$. Since your question is asking for $z$ that gives $P(Z < z) = 0.1 < 0.5$, it must be covering *less* area than the range $Z < 0$, meaning that $z < 0$. Based on that, you definitely should be getting a negative value for $z$.

It's likely that your reference for the normal distribution (whether it's a table, or a calculator function, or whatever) is returning the value of $z$ for $P(Z > z) = 0.1$, which is on entirely the wrong side of the mean for what you're trying to find.